# Import/export manually or Dump Database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a rather heavy database
I have to change server, so I export the database with a dump, then I retrieved it on my new server

But after importing it, the size of the database is different :

- Old server : 772 Mo
- New server : 414 Mo

The difference is enormous, I have to worry? (Do you think there are missing things?)
Is not it better to do an export then an import manually?

Comment: After the retrieval have you checked the consistency (like a checksum) of the dump?

Comment: Thanks, no I did not check anything I do not know how to do a database
I was going to see the differences by comparing .sql files from manual export and dump (like text diff)

Comment: Maybe a diff is a little to heavy. `md5sum database_on_server1.sql` and `md5sum database_on_server2.sql` will do the job

Answer (score 3):

You didn't mention if these size numbers from from the filesystem (`du -ch`, etc), or from a query.  I'm guessing they are from the filesystem.  As long as you didn't get import errors, your data is probably OK.

Check for **FRAGMENTATION** in your SOURCE tables.  That is likely why your source is larger than your target.  Basically, when rows are updated, it may no longer fit in the same data block, and that data block is split into two, leaving some free space in two blocks (16KB used on disk, but 9KB used in the data file).

Check for `fragmented tables`:

`select  ENGINE, TABLE_NAME,Round( DATA_LENGTH/1024/1024) as data_length ,
round(INDEX_LENGTH/1024/1024) as index_length, 
round(DATA_FREE/ 1024/1024) as data_free 
from information_schema.tables 
where  DATA_FREE > 0;`

Check for total disk used and total free space: 

`select  sum((DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH)/1024/1024) as TTL_MB_USED ,
sum(DATA_FREE)/1024/1024 as TTL_MB_FREE
from information_schema.tables 
where  table_schema='<your schema>';`

That may help account for the difference in size between source and target.

I found this answer to be excellent to describe Fragmentation: https://serverfault.com/a/265885

> first at all you must understand that Mysql tables get fragmented when a row is updated, so it's a normal situation. When a table is created, lets say imported using a dump with data, all rows are stored with no fragmentation in many fixed size pages. When you update a variable length row, the page containing this row is divided in two or more pages to store the changes, and these new two (or more) pages contains blank spaces filling the unused space.

Comment: Thank you ! I fact the size numbers come from the filesystem, I go to check my old database with your queries In order to detect inconsistencies